# Typing the click handler when component is generic (polymorphic react component)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

This is my component

```
interface Props<C extends React.ElementType> {
  as?: C;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  size?: "mini" | "small" | "medium" | "large";
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
}

type ButtonProps<C extends React.ElementType> = Props<C> &
  Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithRef<C>, keyof Props<C>>;

export const Button = <C extends React.ElementType = "button">({
  children,
  as,
  size = "medium",
  onClick,
  ...restProps
}: ButtonProps<C>) => {
  const Component = as || "button";

  return (
    <Component {...restProps} className={`button-${size}`} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </Component>
  );
};
```

I can use the component like this:

```
<Button as="a" onClick={(e) => console.log(e)}>Anchor button</a>
```

The problem is that the type for the click handler says the event is of type `React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>`, but it isn't. It should be `HTMLAnchorElement` in this case.

How can I provide the correct type? Ideally I'd somehow use `C` to get the correct `HTMLXyzElement`

Here's a [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgGZwC+cpUEIcARFKhgwNwBQHwAdjElFLokcAAq0whADwBhOEgAe-HgBNCiFjAB0AUQA2SEEj4AVAJ5gkAPlwc4cFIQD8ALjgzO9tAAtgelcw8bsjo2iEYAHIQKkiecITAAF5IrowgvMAMcAA+jIQgKHp6WbkMRirA+CAljHooUADmSOx2cBA8MnrAaADWqQAUSABuxjDBmloAshBESDojfFIAEiaTADIAQvgwMO36hqPY07Pzo1YAlHAAvDZDEMAqnBRcMBYiWzvt4hCSsvJKxjUGlCugMRlMbxsVzEEmkMhsADJWgB5dIwKThbQyOiQHijb6SADqwBg3jIsis2B6SDMEHIBLhVisnA4ikgsDgaHahHgH12PGucD+imUQMxoIOEMsgoYACNtvyGFZ+jhWj4-AFjJhWo5tfYEskZeVKtU9W0Ol1ematDbmDyGRwKG4+V9YRTLjdbF5ufBseB2qNBY4cqV5Z8eC1WswYPgoAL+q17LIcQG+LgbVo7TAGVQ0HVCIQIigjFccAADMP8gC0ABIcAakBQy1R2p1uj1S63LT0KFZE-ZcOr-IFngOhQB6P24s6tc5PFlcng8uBrXg9QUquC7bBDzUCp24LcQNw8qC8BpsTm+YfGcYgzFRGKUD02VX2aOxgVSFBwbzMUilrsvY4LuI5SOOKDMo6LJstA8CLsuLo8AAqsQUAbi+XpwB+cZwAmY5SBUQx9mOSZIfESRIFcZQZFkFSECgsoGCoJGkfY5H8Eo-ZJuOSGsQR5GONRKBZA21HpDwmS-v+1H8DyWRdu2paDJhCEQAYWh6BADQqb23EDhxIr6eBfHGYJhClquPA9ke1HjqJlHibR-GkYZXFsSZCrtC54FEaxc7QUAA) where you can play around with the code if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";

type InferElement<T> =
  T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
  ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[T] extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<any>, infer Elem>
  ? Elem
  : never
  : HTMLElement

type Result = InferElement<'a'> // HTMLAnchorElement

interface Props<C extends React.ElementType> {
  as?: C;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  size?: "mini" | "small" | "medium" | "large";
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<InferElement<C>, MouseEvent>) => void;
}

type ButtonProps<C extends React.ElementType> = Props<C> &
  Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithRef<C>, keyof Props<C>>;

export const Button = <C extends React.ElementType = "button">({
  children,
  as,
  size = "medium",
  onClick,
  ...restProps
}: ButtonProps<C>) => {
   const Component: React.ElementType = as || "button";


  return (
    <Component {...restProps} className={`button-${size}`} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </Component>
  );
};

const Link = ({ to, children }: { to: string; children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return <a href={to}>{children}</a>;
};

export const ButtonUser = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button size="mini" disabled>
        Button text
      </Button>
      <Button as="a" size="mini" href="test" onClick={(e) => console.log(e)}>
        Button text
      </Button>
      <Button as={Link} to="/" size="mini">
        Button text
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

const jsx = <Button as="a" onClick={(e) => console.log(e)}>Anchor button</Button>
```

Since `JSX.IntrinsicElements` is just a big map of html elements, You can infer html element name from `JSX.IntrinsicElements` and use it for callback argument. see `InferElement` util

Comment: I see you do `JSX.IntrinsicElements[T] extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<any>, infer Elem>`. Does this mean the util is limited to AnchorHTMLAttributes? What if I do `as="button"` instead of `as="a"`?

Comment: Please try to replace with any known html element, you will see it work

Comment: Write `<Button as="div" />` and you will see that event is infered accordingly

Comment: I changed the code to just have `HTMLAttributes<any>` and it still seems to work. Feels a little cleaner to me :)

Comment: Where  exactly you  changed?

Comment: I changed `JSX.IntrinsicElements[T] extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<any>, infer Elem>` to `JSX.IntrinsicElements[T] extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<any>, infer Elem>`

Comment: sure, no problem, just wanted to make sure it will be safe enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTMLElement` instead of `HTMLButtonElement`